# Multiple HTML <select> Elements Showing Same Dropdown Content In Ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am refactoring an angularJS webapp to mobile app using Ionic with great success. But, I have two SELECT elements that are not functioning properly anymore. One should select "Months" and the other should select "Years". The problem is, when I click/tap on either, they are both opening the "Years" select options. I thought they might be condensed to close and I was "Fat Fingering" the select elements, but I added margin between and separated them and still happening.

Can someone take a look at the below and tell me if they see anything that could be causing this?

Thanks,

B

```
<div class="card-date-housing">
            <div class="form-group date-select">
                <label for="year" class="item-select security-select">Expiration Month
                <select id="month" class="form-control custom" ng-model="billingInfo.ExpMonth" ng-options="month.id for month in months track by month.id" tabindex="2" required>

                </select>
                </label>
            </div>
</div>
<div class="card-date-housing">
            <div class="form-group date-select">
                <label for="year" class="item-select security-select">Expiration Year
                <select id="year" class="form-control custom" ng-model="billingInfo.ExpYear" ng-options="year.display for year in years track by year.id" tabindex="3" required>

                </select>
                </label>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let me apologize for putting a question here that was so clearly a syntax error. I saw just after I posted this that the labels for attribute was assigned to "year" for both select elements. I changed the "month" label for attribute to "month" and of course it started to behave properly.

Thanks for the community.